# RQ status queued not changing - what's wrong (running on Heroku)?

Tags: flask, heroku, redis, python-rq

I am running a test app on Heroku with RQ. I want to fetch the result of queuing and running function in RQ and send it over to HTML. My code as follows:

Worker.py

```
import os
import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
       worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
       worker.work()code here
```

App.py

```
q = Queue(connection=conn)

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')

def somejob(y):
    import time
    time.sleep(3)
    x = y
    return x

@app.route('/pureredis', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def pureredis():
   job = q.enqueue(somejob,5000)
   id = job.id
   print("id",id)
   job = job.fetch(id, connection=conn)
   print("job",job)
   status = job.get_status()
   print('status',status)
   if status in ['queued', 'started', 'deferred', 'failed']:
      return render_template('redis_1.html', result=status)
   elif status == 'finished':
      result = job.result
      print('result',result)
      return render_template('redis_1.html',result=result)
```

redis_1.html

```
<html>
<head>
{% if refresh %}
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
{% endif %}
</head>
<body>{{ result }}</body>
</html>
```

When I refresh my HTML, following are my server logs:

[image: Server Logs]

My questions - 1) Why is the RQ status not changing and what should I do so that job gets executed. 2) What should I do to grab the result of the function (somejob()) so that I can send it to my HTML through render_template.

Answer (score 0):

Simple snag in code I figured was that the status of the job was being checked too soon. Modified code:

```
@app.route('/pureredis', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
   def pureredis():
   job = q.enqueue(somejob,5000)
   id = job.id
   print("id",id)
   job = job.fetch(id, connection=conn)
   print("job",job)
   time.sleep(4)
   status = job.get_status()
   print('status',status)
   if status in ['queued', 'started', 'deferred', 'failed']:
      return render_template('redis_1.html', result=status)
   elif status == 'finished':
      result = job.result
      print('result',result)
      return render_template('redis_1.html',result=result)
```